# Apex: Setting Properties with the Indexing Notation

Tags: salesforce, apex

Is it possible to set a property on an instance of a class like so;

```java
MyCls item = new MyCls();

item['propName'] = propValue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Apex does not support indexing notation on any object - custom classes, `Map` instances, or sObjects.

You can use the `get()` and `put()` methods on the [`Map`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) and  [`sObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#!) built- classes to access fields by name or `Map` values. However, doing so on an sObject loses you compile-time field checking, and typically requires a lot of casting in statically-typed Apex. It's preferable to use standard access when possible.

This does not apply to custom classes unless you implement your own accessor methods.